# Restrict DROP and ALTER table under specific schema in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have created a user (say DROP_PARTITION_USER) to drop partitions of a table. The table is owned by different user (say NORMAL_USER).
Currently, I have granted **DROP ANY TABLE** and **ALTER ANY TABLE** privileges to DROP_PARTITION_USER. When DROP_PARTITION_USER executes following statement, it gets executed successfully.

```
ALTER TABLE SCHEMANAME.TABLENAME DROP PARTITION <PARTITION_NAME> UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES;
```

But, **DROP ANY TABLE** and **ALTER ANY TABLE**  allows DROP_PARTITION_USER to drop and alter any table under any schema [https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9013.htm ]. 
Is there any way in Oracle to restrict drop and alter table under specific schema?

Comment: Why wouldn't NORMAL_USER maintain its own tables (which includes dropping partitions)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common way to solve this is to create a procedure owned by NORMAL_USER to drop one of the partitions of one of it's tables.

Then you `GRANT EXECUTE` on this procedure to DROP_PARTITION_USER.

You'll need no extra privileges.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_drop_partition (p_table_name VARCHAR2, p_partition_name VARCHAR2) 
IS
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||p_table_name||' DROP PARTITION '||p_partition_name;
END my_drop_partition;
/


GRANT EXECUTE ON my_drop_partition TO drop_partition_user;
```

Comment: So even if DROP_PARTITION_USER does not have  DROP ANY TABLE and ALTER ANY TABLE permissions, will it be able to execute the stored procedure successfully?

Comment: Yes, exactly, that is the standard model of privileges in Oracle. The owner is allowed everything on it's own tables, and the procedure is actually executed by the owner.  If the owner chooses to grant somebody else the right to execute a procedure, then that's absolutely ok. Even the name resolution works like that, so you don't need the schema name of the tables inside the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a DDL trigger to capture such attempts and take whatever action you like.  For example

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER STOP_THAT_STUFF
  2  before create or alter or drop on database
  3  begin
  4    if ora_dict_obj_owner in ('SCOTT') and
  5       ora_sysevent in ('DROP','ALTER') and
  6       ora_dict_obj_name = 'MY_TABLE'
  7    then
  8      raise_application_error(-20000,'What the hell are you thinking!!!!');
  9    end if;
 10  end;
 11  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
SQL> conn scott/tiger
Connected.

SQL> create table scott.my_table(x int );

Table created.

SQL> create table scott.my_other_table(x int);

Table created.

SQL> drop table my_other_table;

Table dropped.

SQL> drop table my_table;
drop table my_table
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SYS.STOP_THAT_STUFF'
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-20000: What the hell are you thinking!!!!
ORA-06512: at line 6


SQL> desc my_table
 Name                                                                    Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------- -------- ----------------
 X                                                                                NUMBER(38)
```